# I have started learning flask and when I run my home.html and submit a form then it gives your files can't be accessed. For backend I have used flask

Tags: python, flask, web-deployment

this is my rule.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>rules</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H1>Have fun and enjoy {{name}}</H1>
        <p>So there are some rules that will help you to play this game.</p> 
    </body>
</html>
```

this one is home page html code. Please help, I saw tutorials but not getting anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to guess the game!!</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/rule">
            <h3>So, what is your name":</h3>
            <input type="text" name="user">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" >
        </form>
    </body>
```

this one is my python code.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, redirect, url_for
app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/rule', methods=["POST","GET"])
def rule():
    if request.method=="POST":
        user=request.form["user"]
        print(user)
        return redirect(url_for("user",usr=user))
    else:
        return render_template("rule.html")

@app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return render_template("rule.html",name=usr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

sorry for so many codes. but i need help.

and my os is window 8.1, python -> 3.7.1, flask->1.1.1,werkzeug->1.0.1

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW42A.png)

Comment: Your app works like a charm on my computer. You lack a lot of information what is going wrong. You need to specify your operating system, what you exactly did, how you run Flask and the complete error message. Also, you need to put your code here, not in a link.

Comment: @J.G. Ihave done it,. can you now help me?

Comment: Could you please add your complete error message? Also include where you put your code on your file system and how you start Flask? Thanks.

Comment: and folder is like guess_the_number_game->pyhon_code.py
                                        ,templates->home.html
                                                   ->rule.html
    and i am using sublime text 3 and i run flask by just ctrl+b...

Comment: @J.G.  it's running correctly and giving me desired result when i run the python code but when i go from home.html then it is giving me the error. it is not calling external file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at your error page, your browser seems to try to access `D:/rule` - this should not be served by the file system, but by Flask.

You need to access your app e.g. as `localhost:5000/home.html` and then it should work.

For me it looks like you directly access the html file in your browser from the file system.

First, you need to run your app, with something like `python main.py`, where `main.py` is the file name of your app.

Then enter the URL, which you see in the console plus append the `home.html` - it should work then.

Comment: Ok I did it and it worked. Thanks a lot @J.G.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you upvote or accept my answer. Thank you!

Comment: I would really like to @J.G. but I think my reputation is less than 15 so can't do it. I am sorry if I just wasted your time :(

Comment: It was a pleasure to help you! And thanks for accepting the answer.